# protocol-buffers: send multiple messages of the same type

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

For example, I defined the following reply message in proto file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

message MyRequest {
   int32 id = 1;
}

message MyReply {
   int32 id = 1;
   int32 group = 2;
   string name = 3;
}

...
```

How can I tell in `.proto` file that MyReply can be received multiple times, i.e. if there is many objects that can be sent together?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly it appears that using a [`repeated`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#specifying_field_rules) field would meet your needs:

```
message ReplyItem {
   int32 id = 1;
   int32 group = 2;
   string name = 3;
}

message MyReply {
   repeated ReplyItem items = 1;
}
```

Comment: thanks! Does this also mean that a single _ReplyItem_ can be sent over the wire, not encapsulated in _MyReply_?

Comment: Well you can send a single stand-alone *ReplyItem* but if the receiver is expecting a *MyReply* it will not decode (see [encoding](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#optional)).

Comment: so in other words I'd need two _Request_ messages, one would expect _ReplyItem_, the other would expect _MyReply_ ?

Comment: Well that is an option. However I'd suggest just accepting the `repeated` option; as this allows sending of 0-many items it meets both needs (yes the call to send a single item is slightly more complex but I feel that adding a second call makes the whole API more complex).

Comment: https://www.grpc.io/docs/what-is-grpc/core-concepts/ talks about streams. It looks to me that a stream contains multiple replies, how different is this from having `repeated` option in reply definition? Thanks!

Comment: A stream is another option but the way this works is quite different. Calling/servicing a streaming call is more complex than a non-streaming call so I'd only suggest using one where there is a need (i.e. passing lots of data or data that is not immediately available).